# Power-on delay using NPN transistor

Tags: power, transistors, npn, delay

I'm looking for a small and simple 1-2 second power-on delay circuit which would power the bluetooth module (20mA @ 3.6V). I have tried to achieve this using 2n3904 transistor, few resistors and capacitor, but unsuccessfully. Various schematics I found on the internet doesn't seem to work as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to delay the power going into the bluetooth module, or a reset signal into the module.  I'm having troubling imagining the NPN only in the first scenario unless your also intending to have a lot of drop out or have some other higher voltage rail available to bias is on.

Comment: I'm trying to delay the power going into the bluetooth module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to achieve this is to use voltage detector with programmable delay e.g. NCP302

Answer (score 2):

This is the power-on delay circuit for the MIDI outputs of the Roland A-50:

[image: Roland A-50 power-on delay circuit]

R15 and R17 set the base current of the PNP transistor (this circuit is designed to supply 25 mA at 5 V). When powering on, C14 needs to be charged before the voltage at the transistor's base is low enough to switch on; the delay is determined by the time constant of C14 and R15. (For 1–2 s, you need a much larger capacitor.) R14 and D1 are optional; they are a path to quickly discharge the capacitor when power is switched off. R18 is optional; it speeds up switching *off* the transistor by allowing its base to be discharged faster.

This circuit switches the positive power rail. If you have only an NPN transistor, you have to reverse everything to switch the other rail (ground).

In either case, the module probably will not be able to withstand any voltages applied to its input pins when it is not powered.